# BlogEngine Paypal

Tags: asp.net, checkout, paypal, nvp

I'm trying to get BlogEngine working with ExpressCheckout. I've tested the API credntials with the same user controls as I'm using with BlogEngine and they work. In BlogEngine, however, I get "Sorry, an error occurred after you clicked the last link". I'm using the same .ascx user control and the same API settings and credentials.

In BlogEngine, if I use Firefox I can get to the PayPal login screen without problems, but with IE or Chrome (IE7 and IE8) on low privacy and security settings, I get the error.

I've tried sandbox and live credentials but I really don't know what else to try. I'm using the MarkExpressCheckout method on PayPal's NVP C# samples and have never had problems before. Could some part of BlogEngine be interfering somehow? I'm running ASP.NET 4.

If it helps, my site/checkout is at http://chickenping.com (http://chickenping.com/category.aspx to add prroducts to the cart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by passing the country as United Kingdom rather than GB (which works)